# Extra element in string literal array of template literals

Tags: javascript, string, literals, template-literals, backticks

For Example, on running the below code -

```js
let a = 5;
let b = 10;

function print(strings, ...values) {
  console.log(strings[0]);
  console.log(strings[1]);
  console.log(strings[2]);
  console.log(values[0]);
  console.log(values[1]);
}

print `add${a + b}mul${a - b}`;
```

Following Output is received -

```
"add"
"mul"
""
15
-5
```

Why there is an extra string literal at the end, even when i provided only only two, **add** and **mul** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's empty string `""` after the `${a - b}`. The last index simply cannot be removed, because it is possible that there's a non-empty string. You get the same behavior by placing two expressions side by side without any string between them (`${...}${...}`). Example:

```js
function tag(...all) {
  console.log(all);
}

tag `a${1}b${2}${3}c`;
```

If you need to get rid of empty strings, you can filter the string array using `Array.filter`, here's an example:

```js
function tag(strings, ...values) {
  console.log(strings.filter(Boolean)); // filters arary, "" == false
  console.log(values);
}

tag `a${1}b${2}${3}c${4}d${5}`;
```

Output is

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

instead of:

```
["a","b","","c","d",""]
```